# What are the top three options for user authentication on iOS in 2017?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm building a new iOS app that needs the concept of who the user is logged in as. It seems my options are:

1. Build my own login system, make them enter email, generate password.
2. Use Facebook or Twitter accounts (or linkedin, google, etc.)
3. Use Apple ID?

Number 3 seems like a nice apple way but is that even supported? I'm logged in to my iPhone already in settings with my Apple ID. Could I use that?

My question is, it's 2017, what's the latest and greatest way to do this. I have a green field iOS app and can pick any authentication system I want. What say you SO community? Thanks!

Comment: It's clearly a "primarily opinion-based" question. Also, it's between coding and UX. What's seems "less annoying" for the user? Already connect with it's FaceBook or similar account? Does it have a benefits to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Authenticating on iOS

When building a login system for iOS it's important to remember that Apple demands that you support multiple login options for you app. You can't e.g. use only Facebook for login or only Google login. A time ago I got this reply from Apple:

> In order for Facebook to be the only authentication mechanism available, your app must include significant account-specific functionality from Facebook. Pulling profile information, or sharing, are not sufficient account-based features for Facebook to be the only authentication mechanism available.

So the option will need to use e.g. custom login + social medium login or several social medium login. 
I have seen that a custom login/username+password and the use of social medium authentication is the most used practice. It offers users often *one click* authentication and authorization. By using social medium, you can get users profile information without asking the users about their information.

Authentication mechanisms:

1. [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios)
2. [Twitter/Fabric](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/twitter/log-in-with-twitter.html)
3. [Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating)
4. [email/password(custom)](https://oauth.net/2/)

Framework:

1. [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com)
2. [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios)
3. [Twitter/Fabric](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/twitter/log-in-with-twitter.html)
4. [Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating)
5. [Parse(Discontinued)](https://parseplatform.github.io)
6. Custom

**What do I do?**

For a small team/single developer it's easy and fast to develop using Firebase as a authentication service. There's no need for another programming language that what you write your apps in; swift/objective-c.

**Firebase**

> Firebase is a mobile platform that helps you quickly develop high-quality apps, grow your user base, and earn more money. Firebase is made up of complementary features that you can mix-and-match to fit your needs

Firebase is a really great tool for building a login system for your app. It does all the backend services for you and supports login systems for Facebook, Google, Twitter, Github and email/password authentication.

**But should you use an authentication mechanism in your app?**

> If your app doesn’t include significant account-based features, let people use it without a log-in. Apps may not require users to enter personal information to function, except when directly relevant to the core functionality of the app or required by law. If your core app functionality is not related to a specific social network (e.g. Facebook, WeChat, Weibo, Twitter, etc.), you must provide access without a login or via another mechanism. Pulling basic profile information, sharing to the social network, or inviting friends to use the app are not considered core app functionality.

[Ref.](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

> Number 3 seems like a nice apple way but is that even supported? I'm logged in to my iPhone already in settings with my Apple ID. Could I use that?

Could be a good approach, but Apple have no API/Documentation on that. There is a unique identifier available on iOS devices, though it is not guaranteed that the [UUID](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsuuid)(Unique identifier) will be the same after rebooting and software reinstalls. (Can't find the source at the moment, can someone verify this?)

Apple do have a framework for using the [touchID](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/711/) provided on iOS8+ to authorize users login into you app using the keychain. But this does not provide a authentication framework for you app.

Comment: this is a better answer than I could have possibly imagined.  Thank u Joakim. No thank u  Eric Aya, Larme, dan, Losiowaty, and EmilioPelaez.